# Optimal strategy for this d6 game

Tags: probability, game-theory, expected-value, dice

In my attempts to learn the foundations, I was given the following game in a mock interview:

> Two players each roll a d6, and are not able to see each other's
>   rolls. The player with the higher value wins \$1. After the players
>   roll their dice, each player may either pay \$0.25 to increase their
>   individual roll by 2 or keep their roll. What is the optimal strategy
>   and payout? Consider the cases for which i) nothing happens when both
>   players roll the same number, and ii) the players keep rerolling (for free) until
>   different numbers appear.

What is the best strategy here? Is it important for both players to have the same strategy for Nash/symmetric equilibrium (not sure what the terminology I should be using is)? What should my considerations be in calculating the expected value? Please help prod me to attempt deriving the strategy, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the probability distribution of the other person's roll be $P(i)$.

**Hint:** If you roll a $n$, what will make you indifferent to pay $0.25$ to increase your roll?

> You are indifferent if $P(n) + P(n+1) = 0.25$.

Is there a probability distribution when you are always indifferent?

> The probability distribution is $P(i) = \frac{1}{8}$. (Each outcome is equally likely)

If yes, can that be achieved via the rules?

> It can be achieved. Specifically, what is the strategy?

If yes, is that a symmetric Nash equilibrium?

> Yes, see comment.

If yes, what is the payout?

> The payout under case 1 is $\frac{5}{16}$, under case 2 is $\frac{1}{2}$. Why?

Is this the max possible payout? Why, or why not?

Case 1: (I had an error so now I'm not certain)

Case 2a: My interpretation for Case 2 was that they don't have to pay the \$0.25 and get to reroll. If so, the total payout in each turn is 1, and since the strategy is symmetric, hence the max payout is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Case 2b: An equally valid interpretation is that they will have to pay the \$0.25 regardless. Under this interpretation, it's not immediately clear to me what the strategy should be.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer — isn’t the PMF itself affected by the strategy? For example whether I choose to increase when I roll a 6 will affect the probability mass of attaining an 8?

Comment: Your opponent's pdf is fixed. Determine your best response to a given distribution.

Comment: sorry for another silly question — but I don’t see why the opponent’s PMF should be fixed. Are they also not trying to optimise their strategy according to what they think our strategy is too?

Comment: For NE, each strategy is a Best Response to the other. So, a good first step is "Given any strategy (fixed pdf), what are the best response?". After that, identity pairs of mutual best responses, which gives us a NE. In particular, if there is a strategy S that the best response is every strategy (IE you're indifferent), then (S, S) is a NE. As an example, in Rock Paper Scissors. The play-all-equally strategy $S = (1/3,1/3,1/3)$ makes the other player indifferent since the expected win = 0 always. (Note: I'm not saying that this is the only way to obtain a NE, as it is not).

Comment: Neither am I claiming that "this sequence of steps is how you should approach all such problems". I'm claiming that "this sequence of steps works for this problem".

Comment: hi, I don’t see where you get 1/2 for case 2, could you explain in more detail please?

Comment: I've added more details. It's open to some interpretation.

Comment: I obtained increasing our roll with probability 3/4 if we rolled 5 or 6, 1/2 if 3 or 4, or 1/4 if 1 or 2. Is there an easier way to solve for the payouts than to consider the individual payoffs for what the opponent’s number is what my roll is/whether I choose to increase my value? Also, when you say max payout, does that mean across all possible solutions to our simultaneous equations? What’s wrong with a strategy that say increases for roll > some k?

Comment: Also by manually calculating the expected value I got 5/16 instead of 7/16. I noticed my sum eventually became 6/8+5/8+...+1/8+0-1/8. Did I miss out something?

Comment: The easier way is A) 1/8 of the time, no one wins, otherwise the payment is 1. So, the expected amount received is (1-1/8)/2  = 7/16, and B) 1/2 of the time you pay 1/4, so must subtract 1/8 to get 5/16 (I forgot about this, which is why my calculation was off by 1/8.)